# Пример с оператором if из книги

Tags: java

Из книги: Давайте изменим метод dive() в классе Fish, чтобы ограничить сотней метров глубину, на которой может плавать наша рыбка:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Fish myFish = new Fish();
        myFish.dive(50);
    }
}




public class Fish  {
    int currentDepth = 0;

    public int dive(int howDeep) {
        currentDepth = currentDepth + howDeep;
        if (currentDepth > 100) {
            System.out.println("Я маленькая рыбка и не могу плавать глубже 100 метров");
            currentDepth = currentDepth - howDeep;
        } else {
            System.out.println("Я погружаюсь еще на " + howDeep + " метров");
            System.out.println("Я на глубине " + currentDepth + " метров");
        }
        return currentDepth;
    }
}
```

Всё работает, но я не понял зачем вот эта строчка:

```
currentDepth = currentDepth - howDeep;
```

Просто мы сначала простыми словами делаем так:
0 = 0 + введенное число;
Если (currentDepth больше 100) то вывести ... иначе ...

Ну вот только не пойму зачем строчка  `currentDepth = currentDepth - howDeep;`
То есть изначально у нас значение  `myFish.dive(50);`  = 50;

А  `currentDepth = currentDepth - howDeep;` `// это будет 50 = 50 - 50;`
Если и без неё прекрасно всё работает(вроде как).
Объясните пожалуйста!
Где тут логика? Или меня понесло не в ту сторону?

Comment: @Санаев специально для вас есть памятка - https://ru.stackoverflow.com/conduct

Comment: @Санаев придерживайтесь, пожалуйста, профессионального тона в  общении на StackOverflow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- По условию задачи предполагается, что `currentDepth` не должно превышать 100
- Первым действием в методе происходит увеличение `currentDepth` на заданное значение (`howDeep`). Например, `currentDepth` было 80, `howDeep` - 50, в итоге `currentDepth` стало 130
- Если получившееся значение больше максимально допустимого (например, `currentDepth` = 130), то нужно отменить уже произведённое увеличение `currentDepth`. Для этого, собственно, из него и  вычитается уже добавленное значение, чтобы `currentDepth` снова стало равно 80

---

Вообще, это несколько проблемный подход (из-за необходимости откатывать значение, что является усложнённым вариантом дублирования кода). На мой взгляд, проще и понятнее проверять, не выйдет ли новое значение за границы, и изменять текущее только в том случае, если новое значение допустимо:

```
public int dive(int howDeep)
{
    int newDepth = currentDepth + howDeep;
    if (newDepth > 100)
    {
        System.out.println("Я маленькая рыбка и не могу плавать глубже 100 метров");
    }
    else
    {
        currentDepth = newDepth;
        System.out.println("Я погружаюсь еще на " + howDeep + " метров");
        System.out.println("Я на глубине " + currentDepth + " метров");
    }
    return currentDepth;
}
```

Comment: Спасибо большое за такой подробный ответ. Побольше бы таких как вы. Удачи вам!

Answer (score 1):

Возвращаем `currentDeep` к исходному значению, если рыбка не нырнула, т.к. конечная глубина была бы больше, чем рыбка может.

Если же в `if` поставить

```
    if ((currentDepth + howDeep) > 100)
```

то строчка `currentDepth = currentDepth - howDeep;` не потребуется, потому что значение `currentDeep` не будет изменено.